# Creating Histogram with Binning Averages

Tags: r, graphics, average, binning

I am making two histograms by using moving averages and binning. I have gotten a moving average of 18k data points , most that are 0 values ,by using excel.

This is what I was looking to get done through R

["Moving Average"](http://postimg.org/image/rweahsps5/)

I would like to use R in order to make a script that will produce a histogram of how many ‘counts’ a device received.  I have tried :

```
hist(y, 20)  
hist (y, ) 
plot (y, x)
```

and now , after three days of learning this is what I got :

```
y <- AltWithAllCounts$Cts.p.ms
x <- AltWithAllCounts$Alt 
barwidth <- 100 
#how many bins
block <- rep(seq(1,length(x)/barwidth),each=barwidth)
#makes bins
a <- aggregate(y,by=list(block),sum) 
#creates sum of bins
altmean <- aggregate(x,by=list(block),mean)
#finds mean altitude of each bin
avgCount <- a$x/barwidth
#averages out each bin
plot(altmean$x,avgCount,xlab="Altitude",ylab="Counts") 
# creates scatterplot of mean bins
 avgBinCnt <- data.frame(altmean$x,a$x)
write.csv(avgBinCnt,file="avgBinCnt.csv",)
```

The idea is that I want to the average sum of 20 values and plot it over time  , which is x

```
x       y
851304  0
851404  0
851503  0
851603  1
851703  0
851804  0
851904  0
852107  0
852203  0
852303  0
922503  0
922603  2
922703  0
922804  0
922904  0
923107  0
923203  0
923303  0
923404  0
923504  0
923604  0
923703  0
923803  0
923904  0
924108  0
924205  1
1441603 0
1441703 0
1441804 0
1441904 0
1442107 1
1442203 1
1442304 0
1442404 4
1442504 0
1442605 1
1442703 6
1442803 8
1442904 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A histogram shows frequencies, rather than numbers of occurrences in an interval. To get the latter, one can do something like this:

```
# First create some test data
t <- seq(1,20000)
p <- 2000
s <- (sin(t*pi/p)+1)/2
d <- ifelse(runif(length(s))<s,1,0)
# Each element of d now contains a 1 or a 0, with a probability that varies
# according to the sign function
# Choose how many elements to count over
barwidth <- 100
# Create a vector of block numbers, with each numbered block having a length of 
# barwidth
block <- rep(seq(1,length(s)/barwidth),each=barwidth)
# Now we aggregate with the sum to find the number of 1s in each block
a <- aggregate(d,by=list(block),sum)
# And plot it to show that we have the expected result
barplot(a$x)
```

... which gives:

[image]

For a scatter plot of frequency rather than a bar chart of counts, this gives the desired output:

```
midpoint <- aggregate(t,by=list(block),mean)
plot(midpoint$x,a$x,xlab="",ylab="frequency")
```

Or a symmetrical running average can be found and plotted with:

```
filt <- rep(1/barwidth,barwidth)
y_sym <- filter(d, filt, sides=2)
plot(t,y_sym,xlab="",ylab="frequency")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed my data to reflect that I do actually have  values that are larger than 1.

Comment: The method that I showed applies just as well to cases where there is more than one count per period as to cases where there is no more than one count per period. Although I have plotted the sum of the counts rather than the average count, I can get the average count by dividing, e.g. `avgCount <- a$x/barwidth`

Comment: I  updated my post and added a link to the the scatter plot that I was looking to get.

Comment: I am still getting a sin() function printing. I am looking to understand what it takes to write code for the binned average and moving average in a scaterplot like the link that I posted above in the hyper link " Moving Average.

Comment: If you replace my vector `d` with your vector `y` and my vector `t` with your vector `x` in the code above and use the symmetrical moving average code, you will get a graph exactly like you posted.

Comment: I think I finally got it. Thanks for staying with me on this problem. I am a engineering student that is doing some volunteer work at a planetarium in major city and am very grateful that you did help me with this. Is there a place that I can post the R script so other people can reference my comments to this  conversation ?

Comment: Glad to help. You can edit your question to show the complete answer added at the bottom of your problem. While you're doing that, you might also include your example graph and the final graph that you ended up with in your question too -- You can click the "insert picture" icon to do that while you're editing.